# Como escrever uma grande quantidade de valores por linha em arquivo com Python?

Tags: python

Tenho um código de uma simulação física que eu lido com MUITAS INFORMAÇÕES e muitas interações. Por exemplo, eu tenho o cálculo da carga qt, entretanto, são 100 interações e estou trabalhando com um vetor qt de tamanho 101! Preciso salvar os dados desse qt para cada interação que tenho em um arquivo .txt:

```
f2.write('%.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f\n'
    %(qt[0],qt[1],qt[2],qt[3],qt[4],qt[5],qt[6],qt[7],qt[8],qt[9],qt[10]))
```

Esse é um exemplo de quando eu tenho 10 qt's. Como eu faria para generalizar isso de forma que eu não precise escrever 101 vezes o `'%.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f \t %.20f\n'`?

Answer (score 6):

A ação que pretende realizar é juntar, que é dado pelo método [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) da `string`. Esta permite juntar qualquer quantidade de elementos de um iterável utilizando uma string como separador entre eles.

Começando por um exemplo simples, imagine que tem uma lista de 5 elementos:

```
elems = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Se os quiser mostrar numa `string` separados por `,` pode utilizar o `join`:

```
print(','.join(elems)) # 1,2,3,4,5
```

No caso que tem será semelhante, mas a diferença é que cada numero será separado por um `\t` e cada elemento tem de ser formatado com o `.20f` que consegue fazer à custa de [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Logo basta fazer:

```
texto_arquivo = ' \t '.join(map(lambda x: "%.20f" % x, qt)) + '\n'
f2.write(texto_arquivo)
```

Comment: Esse "texto_arquivo", se sugere ao nome que tu deu ao arquivo quando tu deu o comando "f=open...."?

Comment: @BernardoCecchetto Não, o `texto_arquivo` representa a linha de texto que é escrita no arquivo. É apenas uma variável para ficar um pouco mais organizado. É a diferença entre fazer `f2.write('a')` versus `texto = 'a'; f2.write(texto)`. Acabam por ser duas formas diferentes de fazer o mesmo.

Comment: entendi, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode também utilizar o módulo [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), configurando o delimitador manualmente para o caractere `\t`. Ficaria parecido com:

```
import csv

with open('arquivo.txt', 'w') as stream:
    writer = csv.writer(stream, delimiter='\t')
    for i in range(1000):  # Seu laço de repetição...
        valores = [...]    # Sua lista com os 100 valores...
        writer.writerow(valores)  # Aqui escreve a lista inteira no arquivo
```

Simples, fácil e legível.

Answer (score 0):

OI , Bernardo,

Você poderia usar a função join do python. Irá ficar assim:

## Forma 1:

```
f2 = open('saida.txt','w+') # Importante usar o w+ , salvar sem apagar o'que já está lá.

f2.write(''.join([(lambda x: '%.20f \t ' %x)(q) for q in qt]) + '\n')

# Lembrar de usar o f2.close() no final do programa.
```

## Forma 2:

```
f2 = open('saida.txt','w+') # Importante usar o w+ , salvar sem apagar o'que já está lá.

def formatador(entrada):
    registro = ''
    for qt in entrada:
        informacao = '%.20f \t ' %qt
        registro = registro + informacao
    return registro

f2.write(formatador(qt))
```

espero ter ajudado. :)

Comment: Na forma 1 não deveria ter `\t` fazendo o `join`? E na forma 2, o seu laço `for` está errado.

Comment: Obrigado, @AndersonCarlosWoss , já revejo a forma 2. Porém o 1 é para mostrar uma forma simples de juntar sem formatação..

Comment: Não precisa do `\n` pra quebrar a linha? Tipo `registro + '\n'`

Comment: O que não teria utilidade alguma, então por que apresentar algo assim? Não apenas sem formatação como todo o conteúdo estaria concatenado.

Comment: Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss pelo feedback.

Comment: @AlexCiuffa valeu pela observação.